# Error al subir app bundle en PlayConsole. No se puede instalar en Android 12 o versiones

Tags: android, flutter, google-play

He intentado subir una version de mi app en PlayConsole, pero desde la ultima versión que he querido subir, me aparece este error, refiriendo a una actividad, un alias de actividad, un servicio o un receptor de emisión con filtro de intents, pero sin establecer la propiedad android:exported.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es necesario cambiar algo del SDK objetivo o SDK minimo?

los tengo asi en Android Manifest:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="21"
    android:targetSdkVersion="31" />
```

y asi en el build.gradle:

```
defaultConfig {
    // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
    applicationId "com.app.blog"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 31
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Abre el archivo Android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml, te aparecerá algo como esto:

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.apitest">
   <application
        android:label="apitest"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">

        <!-- aquí en la etiqueta activity debería aparecer el atributo android:exported="true" como se ve más abajo -->
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            ...
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        ...
        </activity>
 </application>
</manifest>
```

Solo verifica que el atributo android:exported="true" exista en tu etiqueta activity. Igual si ahí tienes más de dos activity debes agregar ese atributo a cada una y así igual con los service, etc tal como te dice el mensaje de error, solo toma en cuenta esto:

- Si está en true: quiere decir que tu actividad puede ser llamada de forma directa por cualquier otra aplicación o servicio del dispositivo, incluso si no es tuyo
- Si está en false: pues obvio permanece de cierta manera privado para uso interno de tu app

Una vez que hayas agregado los atributos que falten ejecuta tu app para ver que nada se rompió y vuelve a compilar tu aab, ya no debería darte ese error

NOTA: Solo recuerda que como ya subiste un aab debes de cambiar el codigo de compilación para que Google Play Console te deje subir uno nuevo, en tu pubspec.yaml cambia la línea de versión aumentando un entero al bnúmero después del +:

```yaml
version: 1.0.0+1 # quedaría como version: 1.0.0+2
```